# Filter generic IQueryable in method with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I'm currently working on a filter for a LINQ query in ASP.NET 4.5. I retrieve 2 different `IQueryable` of different table types.

I would call my filter method this way:

```
var result = new Dictionary<DateTime, MyData>();

if(x = 1)
{
    var base = (from t in ctx.OldProjctStatistic
                 select t);

    result = GetProjectData(base);
}
else {
   var base = (from t in ctx.NewProjectStatistic
                 select t);

   result = GetProjectData(base);
}
```

I would need to write a method to filter this result independant of it's type. My current implementation looks like this:

```
private static Dictionary<DateTime, MyData> GetProjectData(IQueryable<T> base) where T : class
{
    // this method stub doesn't work unfortunately
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error on declaration of my filter method:

> Constraints are not allowed on non-generic constraints

Do you know how to write a generic method, to filter results of 2 different types?

Thank you!

Comment: you simply missed the `<T>` at the signature `GetProjectData<T>(IQueryable<T> base)`. Note that `base` is a keyword and I would avoid using it as a parameter or variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the parameter `T` to be recognized as a generic parameter it has to be enclosed in `< >` parentheses which denote a generic parameter. Further more this has to be included in the signature of the method if you want to apply contraints in this method on the generic parameter:

```
private static Dictionary<DateTime, MyData> GetProjectData<T>(...) where T: ...
```

if the compiler cannot find the declaration in the method it will search on class level, whether it can find a generic class

```
public class MyClass<T>{...}
```

If it cannot find either cases it will assume that `T` is simply some object type (may be you own invention) and tell you that you cannot constrain a normal type because it is already defined...

For more information on [generic methods an constrains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) follow the link to the Microsoft programming-guide

Comment: Thanks Mong Zhu for this detailed explanation!! :)

Comment: @john.1020 you are welcome. You really should consider changing the name of the parameter, `base` is a keyword to access the members of a parent class like `this` is to access the members of the current class. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Generic constraints are only possible in generic methods. So you have to make your method generic:

```
private static Dictionary<DateTime, MyData> GetProjectData<T>(IQueryable<T> base) where T : class
{
    // this method stub doesn't work unfortunately
    return null;
}
```

You don't have to change your call, since the type argument can be inferred.